# Does GraphQL introspection work on a federated system?

Tags: graphql, introspection, apollo-federation

If I have a federated GraphQL solution, where each subgraph has ownership over their own schema and resolvers, would I be able to use GraphQL introspection to query the shape of the data across all the schema? Or am I restricted to introspection on one subgraph at a time.

Tried looking for more information about federated implementation, but can't find any answers on this topic.